# What is the type of nut and tool to be used to unscrew?

Tags: torque

[image: Image 1 - what type of nut it is? what tool I have to use to open it?]

[image: Image2 - what type of lock it is? what tool I have to use to open it?]

Please see the two images. I marked a nut and locking part. what type of nut and lock mechanism it is? and what is the tool I have to use to open it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hold the shaft (in a vise with protective jaws) and turn that nut with a "C" spanner - which looks like a C with a single protruding tooth.

[image]

A poor method is to use a drift or punch, but this always damages the nut - perhaps fine for a temporary repair...

Edit as Fred says that is a circlip, actually in internal circlip which means that the nut above needs to be removed first then that circlip will come out.

Comment: Thanks. What is that other part that I marked in the second image? what the name of that nut?

Comment: Called C nuts... as for the other pic - need more detail - may just be the face edge of a clamping nut for the bearing...

Comment: The second photo shows a circlip, the size of which I've never seen before, but is clearly that type of retainer.

Comment: Sometimes also called a collet wrench and collet nut, due to one of their more common uses.